# What does the "4" in LCOM4 mean?

Tags: object-oriented, code-quality, code-smell, code-metrics

I know that methods in a class should have high cohesion which roughly translates to having all the methods use all the instance variables directly or indirectly. I know that *LCOM4* (Lack of cohesion)metric is useful for having a quantitative figure of how much cohesive the methods in a class are. A class with a LCOM4 value of 1 will be considered pretty good while a class with LCOM4 value of, say, 10 is considered a poorly designed class and this probably tells that we are better off decomposing the original  class into 10 separate classes. All this is okay but what does the *4* signify in *LCOM4* metrics?

Comment: not sure about it, but here: http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/pros-and-cons-of-the-lcom4-metric-in-sonar/ they say it stands for "4th attempt to make it right" :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LCOM4 is the fourth version of LCOM.

See http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-cohesion.html#LCOM4, under the subheading "Readings for LCOM4."